# SSRS range chart series labels overlap and do not align left

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008, sql-server-data-tools

I have built a "gantt" style range chart in SSRS using Narayana Palla's model. I am using date parameters to view the data by a date range - my dataset is museum exhibitions over a number of years. I have opted to use the DrawSideBySide  = false custom attribute to display series data but I can not position the series labels as I want. I want them to align left however they align right and overlap with each other. I have tried many different combinations of properties including the smartlabel properties but can not impact on the position of the labels in the series. I have not been able to find a solution in my searching.

I would be happy to have my series displayed using DrawSideBySide = true but the bars are so narrow that neither they nor their labels can be seen. Again I have tried many combinations of properties to set the width of the bars but to no avail. I believe this is due to the number or series in the whole of my chart / dataset.

I would like advice on :
1. How to adjust the position of the labels in the series OR 
2. How to fix the width of the series bars so that I can see them on my chart OR
3. If I am right about the size of the data set making the bars miniscule how can I best resolve this  - say group on year so that only a limited (and therefore hopefully wide) set of series bars appear at a time from page to page.

Very grateful for any assistance, Sally

Answer (score 0):

In SSRS, for the label overlapping issues, the only way is manually changing the chart area size to make enough space for those labels. Otherwise we have change an appropriate chart type.

Comment: Thanks very much for responding. I have used the maximum chart area size and I don't see that I can change the chart type - I need the horizontal range bar chart to create the gantt type chart. Can you offer any advice on limiting the data series by, for instance, grouping on year - perhaps in a list control?